# WebSockets or Http which one to use for real time applications?

Tags: java, http, servlets, websocket

I have done about 70% of the work, using the http(doGet/doPost) methods and now there is requirement of sending a personal message from user1 to user2, which I think can be done by using WebSockets. I just want to whether is it possible to use WebSockets for some work and rest of the application works on HTTP or I will have to change all the server side code in order to use the WebSockets ?

p.s.: If it is possible to use WebSockets for some part and rest of the application works on HTTP, then how should I proceed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

webSockets are 100% compatible with http requests.  In fact, the webSocket protocol was specifically designed so that it could easily be handled by the same server and port that you are using for http requests.  Going even further, a webSocket connection event starts with an http request and then, after the two sides agree, the protocol is "upgraded" to webSocket.

The usual way to proceed would be to obtain a library for your Java server that supports webSockets and make sure it is configured to work on the same port and server as your web server.

If, however you are thinking that you can make a webSocket connection directly from one client to the other, that is not how it works.  webSockets connections go from a browser to a server.  If both clients connect to the same server, then you can use the server as an intermediary to pass a message from one client to another.

Answer (score 1):

You can use both at the same time.

Comment: can you please guide me, how to use both ? just a prototype so that I can start.